# Concrete Categories Where Epis are Just Surjections

Tags: soft-question, category-theory

Before I begin let me provide some background to fix notation/make the post more readable to interested outsiders. In a category $\mathscr{C}$ we say that a morphism $X\xrightarrow{f}Y$ is an epimorphism provided given any two morphisms $g_1,g_2:Y\to Z$ with the property that $g_1\circ f=g_2\circ f$ one may conclude that $g_1=g_2$. In simpler terms, they are "right cancellative". In most "nice" concrete categories the epimorphisms are precisely the surjective morphisms (for example in $\bf{Grp}$, $\bf{Mod}-R$, $\bf{Ab}$, $\bf{Vec}_k$). But, in some concrete categories this isn't true. For example we know that not all categories have this property. For example, in $\bf{Ring}$ the morphism $\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ is a non-surjective epimorphism since any morphism out of $\mathbb{Q}$ is determined by its action on $\mathbb{Z}$ (I'm sure the generalization of this counterexample is obvious). Anyways, I was wondering if there was some kind of characterization, or more realistically intuition, for when a given concrete category has the property that the epimorphisms are precisely the surjective morphisms.

Thanks!

Comment: For convenience the Wikipedia entry for [epimorphims](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimorphism). Wiki has a few more examples of categories where epic does not imply surjective.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Another category where all epimorphisms are surjective is the category of all topological spaces. Indeed, let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces, and let $f\colon X\to Y$ be an epimorphism. Let $Z=\{0,1\}$ endowed with the indiscrete topology, and let $g\colon Y\to Z$ be the characteristic function of $f(X)$. If $h\colon Y\to Z$ is the constant function $1$, then $gf = hf$, hence $g=h$, so $f(X)=Y$. On the other hand, in the category of Hausdorff topological spaces, $f\colon X\to Y$ is an epimorphism if and only if $f(X)$ is *dense* in $Y$.

As far as I know, there is no simple characterization even in the case of concrete categories, even in the case of categories of algebras. Isbell's dominions are a common tool to study the question (see [this answer for the references](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63018/showing-two-ring-homomorphisms-that-agree-on-the-integers-must-agree-on-the-rati/63022#63022) which by the way also contains the characterization of dominions in the category of semigroups). Also [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26934/restriction-of-scalars-reference-or-suggestion-for-proof/26965#26965), which includes the statement of the corresponding theorem for rings; and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57749/whence-this-generalization-of-linear-independence/57972#57972).

Getting into some of the stuff I find interesting, which is restricted to varieties of groups (a *variety of groups* is a full subcategory of groups that is closed under subgroups, homomorphic images, and arbitrary direct products; equivalently, the category of all groups that satisfies a set of identities):

It's not even known which varieties of groups have the property that all epimorphisms are surjective. For example, the inclusion $A_n\hookrightarrow A_{n+1}$ is an epimorphism in the variety generated by $A_{n+1}$ if $n\geq 4$. More generally, for all except a couple of finite nonabelian simple groups $S$, if $\mathfrak{V}$ is the variety generated by $S$, then there is a proper subgroup $H$ of $S$ such that $H\hookrightarrow S$ is an epimorphism. See *Dominions in varieties generated by simple groups*, Algebra Universalis **48** (2002), 133-143, MR 2003h:20051. (The paper does not prove the statement about "all except a couple", but it gives a characerization of which subgroups would be epimorphically embedded, and except for a few "small" simple groups of Lie type with $p=2$, they all have such subgroups.)

Peter Neumann proved that any full subcategory of **Group** which is closed under quotients and in which every group is solvable has the property that all epimorphisms are surjective. (*Splitting groups and projectives in varieties of groups*, Quart. J. Math. Oxford (2)  **18** (1967), pp 325-332). This was generalized somewhat by Susan McKay (*Surjective epimorphisms in classes of groups*, Quart. J. Math. Oxford (2) **20** (1969), pp. 87-90), to any quotient-closed class of groups that lies between a variety of the form $\mathfrak{A}\mathfrak{V}$ and one of the form $\mathfrak{S}\mathfrak{V}$, where $\mathfrak{A}$ is a nontrivial variety of abelian groups, and $\mathfrak{S}$ is a variety of solvable groups.

In *Nonsurjective epimorphisms in decomposable varieties*, Algebra Universalis **48**,
145–150 (2002). MR 1929901(2003h:20052), it is shown that:

**Theorem.** *Let $\mathfrak{V}=\mathfrak{NQ}$ be a nontrivial decomposition of the variety of groups $\mathfrak{V}$. For $G\in\mathfrak{V}$ and $H$ a subgroup of $G$, the following are equivalent:*

1. *$H\hookrightarrow G$ is an epimorphism in $\mathfrak{V}$;*
2. *$H\mathfrak{Q}(G) = G$ and $H\cap\mathfrak{Q}(G)\hookrightarrow \mathfrak{Q}(G)$ is an epimorphism in $\mathfrak{N}$;*
3. *For every normal subgroup $N\triangleleft G$ such that $N\in\mathfrak{N}$ and $G/N\in\mathfrak{Q}$, $HN=G$ and $H\cap N\hookrightarrow N$ is an epimorphism in $\mathfrak{N}$.*

(Above, $\mathfrak{Q}(G)$ is the $\mathfrak{Q}$-verbal subgroup of $G$).

In particular, a decomposable variety of groups has nonsurjective epimorphisms only if the first indecomposable factor has nonsurjective epimorphisms. I've conjectured that the condition is also necessary.

Comment: Absolutely fascinating Arturo, thank you. I have a lot to think about!

Comment: @AlexYoucis For an interesting dual question: can you think of a naturally occurring category of groups in which not every monic is one-to-one?

Comment: Of course, this is an equally interesting question which morally should have the same level of difficulty.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I've been 'trying' (the operative phrase here) to understand the last bit of what you wrote (the last most bit, about the group varieties). I have only ever seen varieties of groups when I did a finite group theory course a while back, and even then we barely covered it. I seem to remember it had something to do with the commutator calculus..or something. Some set of "laws" that the groups are held to. I don't have access to my books right now, but would Robinson be a good reference for this?

Comment: @Alex: Yes, a variety of groups consists of all groups that satisfy a certain set of laws. Examples: abelian groups; solvable groups of length at most $k$; nilpotent groups of class at most $c$; groups of exponent $n$ ($x^n=1$ for all $x$). Robinson has a little bit about varieties (section 2.3). The classic reference is Hanna Neumann's *Varieties of Groups*, from 1967.

Comment: @Alex: Actually, finding monics-that-are-not-one-to-one seems to be much more difficult, because any class of algebras that has a "free object on one generator" will satisfy that monics are one-to-one, and most "naturally ocurring" categories of algebras do.

Comment: Yes, I realized this after I left! Also, there is something hidden in my memory about the result for epimorphisms being true if our category is preadditive?