# Does this definition of an epimorphism work?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

I'm reading through Aluffi's Algebra Chapter 0 and one of the exercises is to come up with a definition of an epimorphism and show that a map $f \colon A \to B$ is surjective iff it is an epimorphism.

In hindsight it's obvious to say that **(Definition 1)** $f$ is an epimorphism if for all maps $g_1, g_2 \colon B \to Z$, if $g_1 \circ f = g_2 \circ f$, then $g_1 = g_2$ (right-cancellation).

However, when I first approached the problem I had something about existence in mind and I came up with the following diagram:

[image: Commutative diagram]

Here, I wanted to define an epimorphism as follows: **(Definition 2)** $f$ is an epimorphism if for all maps $g \colon Z \to B$, there exists a map $h \colon Z \to A$ such that $g = f \circ h$.

In that case, a proof would go as follows (I will assume all sets $A,B,Z$ are nonempty):

Suppose $f$ is surjective. Then, for all $b \in B$, the preimage $f^{-1}(\{b\})$ is nonempty, so we can pick an element $a_b \in A$ such that $a_b \overset{f}{\mapsto} b$. Now if $z \overset{g}{\mapsto} b$ for $z \in Z$, then we can let $h(z)=a_b$. We can repeat this exercise for any $b' \in B$ that is mapped to under $g$.

On the other hand, suppose $f$ is an epimorphism according to Definition 2. Choose an element $b \in B$ and let $g$ be the constant map $g(z) \equiv b$. Then there exists a map $h \colon Z \to A$ such that $f(h(z))=g(z)=b$, so there is some $a \in A$ mapping to $b \in B$ under $f$. Again we can repeat this for any $b' \in B$.

**Question 1** Is my proof correct and the definition sound?

**Question 2** If the answer to Q1 is yes, then I assume I didn't just invent some new property in category theory but rather that this is some property that possibly has a name. (Would it qualify as a universal property?)

Comment: Note that in some concrete categories we find epis which are _not_ surjective maps. A simple example is the category of topological spaces, where the inclusion $\mathbb Q \to \mathbb R$ is epic (satisfies def.1) but not surjective (and violates def. 2). Bonus: it is also monic (since it's injective), but not an isomorphism.

Comment: A more algebraic standard example of what @chi points out: The inclusion $\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Q$ is an epimorphism in the category of commutative rings. Obviously it is not surjective.

Comment: Thanks, this adds some good context as to why 'epimorphism' isn't just another term for 'surjective' or 'onto'.

Comment: Errata to my comment above: the inclusion $\mathbb Q \to \mathbb R$ is epic in the category of *Hausdorff* topological spaces, since there a function $\mathbb R \to X$ is uniquely determined by its behavior on rationals. See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76539/concrete-categories-where-epis-are-just-surjections) for more discussion, and a proof that in the category of *all* topological spaces all epis are in fact surjective.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your definition doesn't work in general, basically because of algebraic obstructions.

For instance, imagine $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2$ is the usual "reduce mod $2$" map in the category of groups. Then taking $g : \mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathbb{Z}/2$ to be the identity map, we have a picture like yours, but notice there *is no map $h : \mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathbb{Z}$* making the diagram commute. In fact, the only group homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/2 \to \mathbb{Z}$ is the trivial homomorphism. I'll let you explicitly work through why your proof doesn't work on this example, because I think it will be a good exercise ^_^.

However, you're not far off from a very useful criterion! We say that $Z$ is a [projective object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_object) in a category if for every epimorphism $f : A \twoheadrightarrow B$ and every map $g : Z \to B$, we have a lift $h : Z \to A$ making the triangle commute. Notice this is a condition on $Z$, rather than a condition on $f$! In $\mathsf{Set}$, *every* object is projective (this is equivalent to the [axiom of choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice)) so we can always detect epimorphisms by checking if a lift exists! Unwinding the fancy words gives basically the same proof that you gave (which *does* work in the category of sets), but it fails in other categories because of the lack of projectives.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you, I think I see it! In my proof I tacitly assumed $h$ is just a function, but if we talk about groups, I would also have to check that $h$ is a group homomorphism (not just some arbitrary map). In your example with $\mathbb{Z}/2$ and $\mathbb{Z}$, we would need $h$ to be the inclusion map, but then $h(1+_{\mathbb{Z}/2}1) = h(0) = 0  \neq 2= h(1)+_{\mathbb{Z}}h(1)$. The lifting criterion for projective objects is interesting (sorry if this is not the correct terminology)!

Comment: @user2978125 -- That's it exactly! ^_^

Comment: Also, if you keep going with Aluffi's book, you'll meet projectives objects again in "Linear Algebra, Reprise"

Comment: Perfect, thank you! (+1 for good exercise)

Answer (score 11):

> Question 1 Is my proof correct and the definition sound?

Yes, though the proof that surjective maps have this property uses the axiom of choice, which is fine.

> Question 2 If the answer to Q1 is yes, then I assume I didn't just invent some new property in category theory but rather that this is some property that possibly has a name. (Would it qualify as a universal property?)

This is equivalent to the map being a [**split epimorphism**](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/split+epimorphism). A morphism $f : A \to B$ is a split epimorphism if there exists a map $g : B \to A$ such that $f \circ g = \mathrm{id}_B$. That is, $f$ must have a right inverse.

Assume $f$ has your property. Then applying it with $g = \mathrm{id}_B$, the $h$ in your property is a right inverse to $f$.

Conversely, suppose that $f$ is a split epimorphism with right inverse $f^\dagger$. Then for any $g : Z \to B$, define $h : Z \to A$ by $f^\dagger \circ g$. Then $f \circ h = f \circ f^\dagger \circ g = \mathrm{id}_B \circ g = g$.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add a higher view on the problem. Consider these four definitions given a morphism $f : A \to B$

- The map $\hom(C,A) \to \hom(C,B)$ induced by composition is *injective* for all $C$.
- The map $\hom(C,A) \to \hom(C,B)$ induced by composition is *surjective* for all $C$.
- The map $\hom(B,C) \to \hom(A,C)$ induced by composition is *injective* for all $C$.
- The map $\hom(B,C) \to \hom(A,C)$ induced by composition is *surjective* for all $C$.

It's easy to see that the standard definition of monomorphism is just the first one, but epimorphism the **third** one. And your purposed definition is the **second** one. These four are called mono, split epi, epi, split mono, respectively. The first and third are the appropriate duals, since being mono in $\mathcal C^{\mathsf{op}}$ is exactly the same as being epi in $\mathcal C$. Thus we give similar names to them. The second and fourth are also duals.

(Also, since this is in a presheaf category, being injective/surjective at each object is equivalent to being mono/epi as presheaves.)